# Truth Question- What is truth?

Tags: discussion, denominations, truth-questions

I am starting to understand that this site is more than what it appeared on first glance. The second I read "secular site," I about left for good. Anyway, I realize this site has specific guidelines here so as to prevent "flame wars" and needless opinionated rants that lead to the equivalent of the lowest-intellect-containing arguments on the internet: YouTube comments. I said all this to say that I want to understand what the term "truth" encompasses. So-called "truth questions" are not allowed because "truth" varies widely among Christians. I get that and that is why I would like any and all (Biblically based) denominational viewpoints to share on the definition of "truth." It is hard for me to define without using the word "true" in some way.

Comment: Related: [Are truth questions inherently off-topic, or just a bad question smell?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1696/21576)

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/20

Answer (score 10):

One of the ways Christianity.SE avoids those flame wars is to insist that answers say what whole groups or denominations *believe* is the truth rather than saying what *is* the truth on a particular topic.

What *is* the truth is a matter of opinion, and there are almost as many opinions as there are people. allowing such "truth" questions and answers leads to discussion and debate, and usually flame wars, which isn't what StackExchange is about. SE is a Q&A site, not a discussion and debate site.

What particular groups or denominations *believe* is the truth is an objectively answerable question. What they believe may or may not *actually* be the truth, but it *is* what they *believe* is the truth. So that becomes a factual matter ("what a church believes") rather than a matter of opinion.

The problem with asking what *all* denominations believe is that there are far too many denominations to cover in a reasonable space. I happen to think that asking in an open-ended way for the views of various denominations can be useful. But the consensus here is that it's too broad, and leads to a "popularity contest" among denominations, which is seen as *not* useful. That's why the mods on Christianity.SE frown on such broad questions, even though theoretically they are objectively answerable.

Comment: "What is the truth is a matter of opinion" Most Christians would believe that there is such a thing as objective truth, but that little of it can be proven or even argued beyond much doubt.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes. The issue is what Christians (and others) *believe* is the objective truth. There's a huge range of *opinion* on what is "objective truth."

Comment: Then ‘truth’ is unable to be found (in the context of a social web site) as it will always be a matter of opinion? For example: God has to reveal what we need to know about Him - truth or opinion? But a Q&S site offers ‘answers’! Statistics would declare - some **have** to be truth. So it is up to the individual to discern the truth? Then I need the help of a superior - such as the Holy Spirit. Interesting......

Comment: Is this also interesting? We can get all the porn (or whatever) we want but we cannot get the truth? How do we get past opinion to the truth? How does a Q&A social site get past opinion to the truth? Who will stand up for the truth? Is that the question? Has our life been reduced to mere debate where all there is is debate and no truth? Faith.....is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen. Isn’t that truth?

Comment: Sorry. I DO understand you points about what SE is about. My mind just got running with some thoughts. I mean no disrespect or put down to SE or any individual related with this question. It just seems there is a level of frustration automatically built in with the site. How do we go about building others up if it’s all simply an opinion? Ok, I will be quiet now.....

Comment: There are so many good answers at SE that you cannot help but bump into the truth. But will you recognize it when you see it? Truth has been shared by individuals and on behalf of entire denominations.